# What data type should I use for both letters and numbers in a same column?

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I want to insert into a table values that contain both letters and numbers (like 'CL005' for example).

What data type should I use for my attribute ? 'number' doesn't work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `varchar` (or `text` if you are using Postgres)

Comment: It will have to be a text data type if you intend to include letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no choice in most databases.  You need to use a string.  I would recommend `varchar()` of some sort.

Some databases support a "variant" type that can hold different types.  To be honest, this is very rarely used.